# Frankfurt Airport drop check luggage early in the morning (long time before the Airline's counters open)?

Tags: luggage, germany, check-in, fra, vietnam-airlines

I will travel by train to Frankfurt Airport very early in the morning (2 am) and I have a big check luggage. The check-in counter for Vietnam Airlines (I will fly to Hanoi, Vietnam) will be opened (around 11 am) before the departure at 1 pm and it is so long time to stay with this big luggage until the counter is opened as I just want to inside the Airport early through passport control and rest on a sofa.

Does the Frankfurt Airport has a service (e.g: self-service kiosk for all Arlines) which one can drop the check in luggage on the same day of the flight out and it is automatically sent to the cabin of his flight?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple luggage storage services in Frankfurt airport including one that's open 24/7 and the service is reasonably priced. See https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/luggage/storage.html

However, there are no services that would hold your bag and then check it in for you later. You will have to do this later yourself when the bag drop or check in counter is actually open.

You can store your luggage bag, rest a few hours and then retrieve your bag and drop it off later. In many cases you can enter and leave the secure area as often as you like. This depends a bit on what type of Visa/Citizenship you have. The only downside is that you will go through security and sometimes exit immigration each time you re-enter.

For more tips on how to spent the night in FRA see also https://www.airportsdata.net/gn/airport-FRA-accommodation/ and https://www.sleepinginairports.net/guides/frankfurt-airport-guide.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I have found a more ideal service called AiRail https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/at-the-airport/AiRailCheck-in.html. I will want to try this one instead of luggage storage which just wastes money and effort to travel back and forth for passport control.
What I expect it can do is, I can drop my check luggage there when I come from the train station at Frankfurt airport.

Comment: However, I'm not sure this AiRail works as I expected, I might be wrong as this sounds too good.

Comment: It should work. But those counters will most likely not be open at 2 am, given that there are no flights at night in Frankfurt. So at this time you would still need to keep your bags on you.

Comment: Not quite clear how that works, but it may be the case that the airline has a check-in counter at that location in addition to the one in the departures hall, and in that case check-in hours are probably the same?